# 2005 4x4 chevy avalanche 1500 While driving Rpms increase but speed does not

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, avalanche

So, on my 05 avalanche, i recently was driving and all of a sudden the Transmission HOT. Message came up on the display, As soon as it did it started sounding funny, revving high rpms, not wanting to shift into the next gear. i had the filter and fluid changed by a professional mechanic. they said there was shavings in the pan but not that bad.  After getting it back i went about 10 miles up the road it ran perfectly fine.. on the way back it started going to high rpms but no speed gain. It also revs high rpms when trying to shift gears sometimes... im not a vehicle guru in any sense and im sorry if my description is lacking. any advice or comments, help would be appreciated. I bought this vehicle from a mechanic i know pretty well. he said it had no issues.  ive had it about 5 months now, and put around 15k miles on it in that time. always change the fluids when they are getting old. not sure what it could be and im worrying i paid alot for this truck only to have it mess up on me = ( ... any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The main issue with the 4L60E always seems to be the sun shell going bad ... however, that usually leaves you without 2nd & 4th. Yours issue seems like you're not getting line pressure, so the clutches are slipping (severely). How well does your reverse work?

Comment: reverse works well altho one time  i noticed it slips when putting it into reverse and its like its in neutral. thats only happened one time as far as i remember

Comment: also this has only started to happen within the last few days... the reverse thing happened once about a month after i bought it.. and has never happened again so far.. i do drive it quite a bit, and i've not noticed any other issues except a display reading service 4x4 ... i was told it was nothing major because it goes into 4x4 just fine when not reading service 4x4. when it does say that on the display it will not go into 4lo or hi.  but it dosent do that very much. i can usually start it fine, and if i need to switch into 4x4 lo or hi and its fine. would that affect it any ? it has been

Comment: very cold here recently idk if that would cause or affect it any, but what ive noticed ( and ive only drove it twice since this started ) once about 2 miles to the mechanics... and the second the 10 miles to town and back. only on the way back did it start acting up but it kept doing it till i got home and it has been sitting ever since. im afraid to drive it as, i paid about 4500. and i dont want to spend half that again already replacing the trans. or 4wd.

Comment: took it to a certified trans. mechanic... going to cost me about 1500$ atleast.... to fix it..